# Cronjob is not working for laravel (linux server)

Tags: laravel, cron, alibaba-cloud

I've tested the cronjob in local which is working fine. But it is not working in server. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

"sudo systemctl status cron" command gives following outputs:

```
 cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-07-19 21:40:44 CST; 27min ago
       Docs: man:cron(8)
   Main PID: 511 (cron)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 2315)
     Memory: 1.9M
     CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
             └─511 /usr/sbin/cron -f

Jul 19 22:05:01 iZa2d4o64ljp79h0v3i5fvZ CRON[2292]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user userr
Jul 19 22:06:01 iZa2d4o64ljp79h0v3i5fvZ CRON[2313]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user userr by (uid=0)
Jul 19 22:06:01 iZa2d4o64ljp79h0v3i5fvZ CRON[2314]: (userr) CMD (  cd /var/www/abc.com.np/myproject/app/Console/Kernel.php && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>>
Jul 19 22:06:01 iZa2d4o64ljp79h0v3i5fvZ CRON[2313]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user userr
Jul 19 22:07:01 iZa2d4o64ljp79h0v3i5fvZ CRON[2333]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user userr by (uid=0)
Jul 19 22:07:01 iZa2d4o64ljp79h0v3i5fvZ CRON[2334]: (userr) CMD (  cd /var/www/abc.com.np/myproject/app/Console/Kernel.php && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>>
Jul 19 22:07:01 iZa2d4o64ljp79h0v3i5fvZ CRON[2333]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user userr
Jul 19 22:08:01 iZa2d4o64ljp79h0v3i5fvZ CRON[2353]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user userr by (uid=0)
Jul 19 22:08:01 iZa2d4o64ljp79h0v3i5fvZ CRON[2354]: (userr) CMD (  cd /var/www/abc.com.np/myproject/app/Console/Kernel.php && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>>
Jul 19 22:08:01 iZa2d4o64ljp79h0v3i5fvZ CRON[2353]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user userr
```

crontab (/etc/crontab)

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.
MAILTO=""


SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name command to be executed
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
*  *    * * *   userr   cd /var/www/abc.com.np/myproject/app/Console/Kernel.php && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
#
```

Kernel.php in laravel project

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Console;
 
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
 
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function () {
        //z;  here if I remove the comment, the error should be shown in storage/log/laravel.log. It works locally but no error is seen in server
            DB::table('recent_users')->delete();
        })->everyMinute();
    }
}
```

Test: here if I've uncommented "//z" inside $schedule->call(), the error should be shown in storage/log/laravel.log if cronjob is working but it does not. It works locally but no error is seen in server

**Update**: I removed the cd

- - - - - /var/www/abc.com.np/myproject/app/Console/Kernel.php && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

the error I got is following:
/var/www/abc.com.np/myproject/app/Console/Kernel.php: 1: cannot open ?php: No such file

Comment: You can't `cd /var/www/abc.com.np/myproject/app/Console/Kernel.php` because that's not a directory. You need `cd /var/www/abc.com.np/myproject/` which is the directory that contains the `artisan` file

Comment: I removed cd. The error I got now is "/var/www/abc.com.np/myproject/app/Console/Kernel.php: 1: cannot open ?php: No such file"

Comment: Thankyou I solved it using following command : *  *  *  *  * php -q /var/www/abc.com.np/project/app/Console/Kernel.php && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1